# Custom Style per Post, How to Display Custom-Styled Single post on Homepage?

Tags: customization, homepage, single

This question probably has simple answer, but I'm not an expert programmer so lemme explain my question chronologically.

I apply custom style for every single post, and it works using the following method. But I have trouble when I want to show my latest post on homepage (included its custom-style). The result I want to, you can see [Trent Walton's Blog](http://trentwalton.com/) for reference.

**This is my method for custom style on every post:**

```
//Custom CSS Widget
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_css_hooks');
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_css');
add_action('wp_head','insert_custom_css');
function custom_css_hooks() {
    add_meta_box('custom_css', 'Custom Styles', 'custom_css_input', 'post', 'normal', 'high');
    add_meta_box('custom_css', 'Custom Styles', 'custom_css_input', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
}
function custom_css_input() {
    global $post;
    echo '';
    echo ''.get_post_meta($post->ID,'_custom_css',true).'';
}
function save_custom_css($post_id) {
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_css_noncename'], 'custom-css')) return $post_id;
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return $post_id;
    $custom_css = $_POST['custom_css'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_css', $custom_css);
}
function insert_custom_css() {
    if (is_page() || is_single()) {
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo 
                '
                    '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_css', true).'
                ';
        endwhile; endif;
        rewind_posts();
    }
}
```

And I add some styles on custom field.

And my style in custom field this will be injected in header of single post. I works.

**On homepage (by creating home.php) I put my latest post, with this:**

```
     get_header();
     ...loop to show the same content as latest single..
     get_footer();
```

And my homepage shows my latest post as I want, but the problem is **its custom style not included**.

**Then I try to modify my conditional tags (fro showing custom style):**
*from*

```
function insert_custom_css() {
    if (is_page() || is_single()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

*to*

```
function insert_custom_css() {
    if (is_home() || is_page() || is_single()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

The result is terrible, it was not showing custom style for the post that currently displayed. **The home post is now styled with my first post custom style**.

I'm looking for you assistance, thanks.

Comment: I getting confused for many hours, so I used [Dave Rupert's plugin](https://github.com/davatron5000/Better-Art-Direction) and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get post custom meta for the page assigned as the site front page, use `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`, which will return that page's ID.

i.e. change this:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_css', true)
```

...to this:

```
get_post_meta( get_option( 'page_on_front' ), '_custom_css', true )
```

...on the site front page (`is_front_page()`)